# Plot image as a point in network graph using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I want to use a dolphin image as the shape of nodes in my network graph using ggplot2. I already read the image; however, I cannot convert it into the type of shape to use it in geom_nodes. Can anyone know how to plot the image as a point in my code, please?

> ```
> library("ggimage")
> library('png')
> img.1 <- readPNG("dolphin.png")
>
>                 
> library(network)
> nodes <- read.csv(file='dolphin_nodes.csv')
> nodes
> edges <- read.csv(file='dolphin_edges.csv')
> edges
> net <- network(x=edges, vertices=nodes, directed = FALSE)
> net
> library(ggnetwork)
> n <- ggnetwork(net)
> library(ggplot2)
> network <- ggplot(n, aes(x=x,y=y,
>                          xend=xend, yend=yend, )) + theme_void() +
>           geom_nodes(aes(size=group, color = group), shape = "square") +
>           geom_edges(color = "grey70") +
>   geom_edgetext(aes(label = group), color = "white", fill = "grey25") +
>   theme_minimal() +
>   theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
>         axis.title = element_blank(),
>         panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey25"),
>         panel.grid = element_blank()) 
> network
> ```

[image: dolphin]

[image: graph]